# in assembly how do i make it that 5 + 5 = 10 and not 0

Tags: assembly

No details needed. I want the result to be 10 instead of 0:

```
section .text
global _start
_start:
    mov eax,'05'
    sub eax,'00'
    
    mov ebx,'05'
    sub ebx,'00'
    add eax,ebx
    add eax,'00'
    
    mov [result],eax
    
    mov edx,2
    mov ecx,result
    mov ebx,1
    mov eax,4
    int 0x80
    
    mov eax,1
    int 0x80
    
section .data
    
segment .bss
    result resb 2
```

i tried chaging the numbers in sub

Comment: then how does it add 4 + 5 = 9

Comment: Because the `add eax, '0'` method only works for single digits. You might want to review the ascii chart. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII-Table-wide.svg